# How come this thread keep running in Spring?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

Guys I could see below code in my legacy application. Once I ran the `main` method, I found this Thread keeps running forever.
But on debugging, why is the Thread running for ever?

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(ResourcesFactoryApplicationContext.getInstance());
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
        applicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
        applicationContext.setConfigLocation("configFileName");
        applicationContext.refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: Somebody who knows more about Spring than I may be able to answer this right away, so this may be a silly request, but can you post the stack trace of the running thread shown in the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure that the thread in question is the thread with `main()`, not some other thread started by one of your Spring beans?

Comment: Every thread will run forever, if it is not a deamon thread.

Comment: More specifically, if a thread is not a daemon, it will run until it reaches the end of its Runnable's run method. If its Runnable is coded so that it never reaches the end of its run method then it will run until somebody kills the process. Anyway, what thread runs forever? Does this snippet reproduce the problem? Include the stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason a process keep running is there are non daemon thread still running. from your code the main thread must have terminated, so the app must have started other threads in one of the  beans.